# undefined variable on foreach ? Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

```
<?php
include 'post.php';
include 'db.php';
mysqli_select_db($pdo, 'ocp') or die('no db connection');
exit();

$q = 'SELECT * FROM posttbl ';
$res = mysqli_query($pdo, $q);
foreach($res as $row){
    $sells[]=array('postid'=>$row['postid'],'title'=>$row['title'],'desc'=>$row['desc']);
}

?>
```

The error is "undefined variable: 'sells'  on line 12..am i missing something? i cant seem to find it..or am i using for each right? this code was actually working at school then when i tried it here at home that error came out of no where. all errors are in line 12 which is

im sorry guys ive re checked the problem and it was on my other page post.php

```
<html>
<body>
<h3>SELLING</h3>

<table border="1" width="50%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php  foreach ($sells as $sell) : ?>  <----------*this is supposed to be the problem
<tr>
<td><?php echo $sell ['title']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

where would i put the "array();" beside the foreach? also sorry about the $pdo i just used it as a variable..i used mysqli for my database...sorry i got the habit of using $pdo as my variable database so sorry its a bad habit.

Comment: Your variable being named `$pdo` is highly suspect, in context of the `mysqli_*()` functions you are calling. Please post the connection code from `db.php`. Also, that `exit()` can't possibly be in your real code, while also getting as far as the `foreach` error.

Comment: You should define the `$sells` variable as an array before trying to append to it. Put `$sells = array();` before the foreach loop.

Comment: Please check the content of $res. My guess is that there are rows with no 'postid', 'title' or 'desc' element.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn That is one of the few variable-related things PHP actually won't issue an E_NOTICE about. If a variable isn't yet instantiated, using it with `[]` will create the array without error or complaint.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: Not necessary.  This is not the actual code, there is an `exit` and line 12 is blank.  None of this code would generate that error.

Comment: Do not rely on the default value of uninitialized variables.  You should always have `display_errors` on and `error_reporting` at maximum level when developing.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Unless there are settings enforcing otherwise, PHP will instantiate and auto assign the array in the loop to a different index of a newly created $sells.

Comment: I see `mysqli_` functions, then I see `$pdo`; that doesn't seem like it's going to start/end well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `include 'post.php';` simply appends the file content at that position.

So you are trying to access variable `$sells` which is actually defined later. You need first to populate the variable, and then to access it.